# WebCam Video Recording in MPEG using C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, webcam, mpeg

I am developing an application which requires me to connect to webcam and record the video in MPEG format as it is VCD compliant. The application is in WinForms however, WPF solution is also fine. I am not interested in WebBased Flash/Silverlight solutions I am only interested in free or opensource solutions or controls.

Is there such solution available for C#/.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following 2 open source projects seem to contain the kind of control you are building.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control

http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The best libraries I know are these.

FFMpeg.NET
FFMpeg-Sharp
FFLib.NET

Other than that, you can do "console" operations to get it done.